# twilio - using a local (behind NAT) HTTP server

Tags: http, twilio, nat, ngrok

The Twilio quick-start pages refer to an HTTP server by FQDN. Great - but most people are probably developing behind NAT.

Answer (score 0):

The apparent solution is to use ngrok, see https://ngrok.com/. at least it makes the HTTP server visible in the internet.